# How to handle filenames with equals signs in GNU Make?

Tags: makefile, escaping, gnu-make

I am trying to automate the processing of files that sometimes contain an "equal sign" with GNU Make. For example, say the filename is called `hello=world.txt` and the `Makefile` is the following:

```
default: hello=world.txt.gz

hello=world.txt.gz : hello=world.txt
        gzip hello=world.txt
        echo done
```

You get the following error:

```
test.make:5: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

How can you escape the equal signs? I have tried backslashes, double quotes and single quotes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one solution:

```
equal := =
default: hello$(equal)world.txt.gz

hello$(equal)world.txt.gz : hello$(equal)world.txt
    gzip hello$(equal)world.txt
    echo done
```

Comment: Not only it works for `=`, but it also works for commas; that is a life saver after fighting misleading "recipe commences before first target" error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Use %=
in makefiles special character must be escaped by %

Comment: Hum.. I tried replacing all "=" with "%=" in the makefile. didn't change the error message.

Comment: okay, in my computer works (I use porteus (slackware linux distribution)).

Comment: I am using `GNU Make 3.82` that's part of RedHat. There appears to be a warning in the NEWS file about that version cannot escape equal signs in prerequisites. So, you might be right.